# How to push video frame to obs server for mobile live streaming on Android

Tags: android, live-streaming, obs

I am an android developer and want to record the video from camera and push them to media server. I want to push the video frames to the obs server.

There server will give me the url and key.

But I don't know how to implement, is it similar to the rtmp?

Can I find the solution from ffmpeg?
Is the any project to study obs develop?

Answer (score 0):

I have find out it, just use rtmp for the obs function.
RTMP stream can be supported by mediaserver.